# Automatically allow-unauthenticated users to cloud run instances

Tags: google-cloud-run

Hi am developing a solution that creates and deploys services to Google cloud run using its REST API with OAuth as a **service account** created fot that purpose.

I am stuck at making the created services available publicly.

I was unable to find a corresponding `--allow-unauthenticated` parameter as with **gcloud** to use from the API.

The only way I found is to manually add `allUsers` as **Cloud Run Invoker** on each service I want publicly reachable. But, I would like all the services from that **service-account** to be automatically reacheable publicly.

I would like to know if there is a better(more automatic) way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you can't do this in only one command. You have to deploy the service and then to grant allUsers on the service. The CLI do this 2 steps conveniently for you.

Anyway, when you are stuck like this, there is a useful trick: add `--log-http` at your gcloud command. Like this, you will see all the HTTP API calls performed by the CLI.

if you do this when you deploy a new Cloud Run service, you will have tons of line and, at a moment, you have this

```
==== request start ====
uri: https://run.googleapis.com/v1/projects/gbl-imt-homerider-basguillaueb/locations/us-central1/services/predict2:setIamPolicy?alt=json
method: POST
== headers start ==
b'Authorization': --- Token Redacted ---
b'X-Goog-User-Project': b'gbl-imt-homerider-basguillaueb'
b'accept': b'application/json'
b'accept-encoding': b'gzip, deflate'
b'content-length': b'98'
b'content-type': b'application/json'
b'user-agent': b'google-cloud-sdk gcloud/299.0.0 command/gcloud.run.deploy invocation-id/61070d063a604fdda8e87ad63777e3ae environment/devshell environment-version/None interactive/True from-script/False python/3.7.3 term/screen (Linux 4.19.112+
)'
== headers end ==
⠹ Deploying new service...
{"policy": {"bindings": [{"members": ["allUsers"], "role": "roles/run.invoker"}], "etag": "ACAB"}}
== body end ==
  ⠹ Setting IAM Policy...
---- response start ----
status: 200
-- headers start --
-content-encoding: gzip
cache-control: private
content-length: 159
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
date: Wed, 08 Jul 2020 11:37:11 GMT
server: ESF
transfer-encoding: chunked
vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 0
-- headers end --
-- body start --
{
  "version": 1,
  "etag": "BwWp7IdZGHs=",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "role": "roles/run.invoker",
      "members": [
        "allUsers"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So, it's an addition API call that perform the CLI for you. You can find [here the API definition](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.services/setIamPolicy)

If you want to perform a call manually, you can do a request like this

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
     -H "content-type: application/json" -X POST \
     -d '{"policy": {"bindings": [{"members": ["allUsers"], "role": "roles/run.invoker"}]}}' \     
     "https://run.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/<REGION>/services/<SERVICE_NAME>:setIamPolicy"
```

Comment: This is exactly the API I missed thanks a lot and an additional thank for the ```--log-http``` trick!